# Would there be better way to avoid duplication in this multi-dimentional data?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, iteration

here's my data from weather API.
I'm trying not to repeat this data, and am not sure if it's even possible to iterate in this kinda data structure.
if anyone knows better way, please let me know.

p.s I shouldn't change data structure and variable name whatsoever for packages I use to achieve a goal.

tried for loops, and map method to iterate this data. However there wasn't an error or data didn't show up on console.

```
const item = this.props.hourly

        let data = [
            { x: item[0].time, y: item[0].apparentTemperature },
            { x: item[1].time, y: item[1].apparentTemperature },
            { x: item[2].time, y: item[2].apparentTemperature },
            { x: item[3].time, y: item[3].apparentTemperature },
            { x: item[4].time, y: item[4].apparentTemperature },
        ]
```

I look forward to better solution to avoid repeat in code.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any duplication of anything. Can you clarify?

Comment: how about ... `let data = item.slice(0, 5).map(({time: x, apparentTemperature: y}) => ({x, y}));`

Comment: where is the question ?

Comment: @ths - it's in the title ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I meant we need some more clarification.

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation guys. @Jaromanda X 's solution is exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate that mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
let data = item.slice(0, 5).map(({time: x, apparentTemperature: y}) => ({x, y}));
```